# Why does rebar use my erl_opts to compile my deps?

Tags: erlang, rebar

I have a structure similar to the following:

```
rebar.config
deps/
apps/A/rebar.config
```

My top-level `rebar.config` file looks like the following:

```
{sub_dirs, ["apps/A"]}.
{lib_dirs, ["deps"]}.
```

`A/rebar.config` looks like the following:

```
{deps, [
    %% deps
    ]}.

{erl_opts, [debug_info, warn_missing_spec, warnings_as_errors]}.
```

Now, one of my dependencies doesn't provide `-spec` for all of its functions, so the `warnings_as_errors` causes the compile to fail.

I was expecting the `erl_opts` to only affect my code, and for the dependencies to have their own options. Why does `rebar` do this?

Comment: Have you tried removing `lib_dirs` from your config file?  I think `deps` is the default dependency directory, and you probably don't need to specify as a `lib_dir`.

Comment: Cannot reproduce it (using your same config) with rebar 2.1.0-pre on R15B03. What version are you running?

Answer (score 2):

It turns out that one of my dependencies doesn't have a `rebar.config`, so rebar is compiling it using my options.

What's confusing is that `erl_opts` is not set in the top-level `rebar.config`, but in a local `rebar.config` file. This is the file that has the `deps` clause.

It seems that the options are inherited "sideways" in this case.

Answer (score 1):

I cannot reproduce this using the following version of rebar:

```
rebar 2.1.0-pre R15B03 20131210_073701 git 2.1.0-pre
```

On my local setup, using your same config (*goldrush* is my dependency):

```
...
==> goldrush (compile)
DEBUG: Matched required ERTS version: 5.9.3.1 -> .*
DEBUG: Matched required OTP release: R15B03 -> .*
DEBUG: Min OTP version unconfigured
DEBUG: erl_opts [debug_info,warn_export_all]
...
==> myapp (compile)
DEBUG: Matched required ERTS version: 5.9.3.1 -> .*
DEBUG: Matched required OTP release: R15B03 -> .*
DEBUG: Min OTP version unconfigured
DEBUG: erl_opts [debug_info,debug_info,warn_missing_spec,warnings_as_errors]
...
```

As you can see, the two applications receive two different sets of options.

Could you enable debugging and post the relevant output?

```
./rebar -vvv clean compile
```

What version of rebar/Erlang are you running?